# Is there a way to get the Marklogic monitoring dashboard Export result as an email

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am looking for something that can provide the monitoring dashboard result,
i.e the excel file that we get after clicking Export button on my Email, after some regular interval of time.

Has anybody done some work on this before ?

Comment: The Monitoring History Excel exports are actually generated in the browser(and then bounced off an endpoint to return with response headers to prompt download or opening in Excel). You could generate something similar server-side. Generating Excel XML is rather tedious (and Excel is rather unforgiving and has terrible error messages that make it difficult to figure out where you went wrong). You might want to look at https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/smallchanges/2007-12-04 or the MarkLogic toolkit for Excel: https://developer.marklogic.com/code/marklogic-toolkit-for-excel

Comment: @mads-hansen why not post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 0):

The Monitoring dashboard is composed of data available from the various xdmp:xxx-status() methods.  One way is to produce a csv or excel file in xquery or javascript, format it as an email using the xdmp email api and schedule it as a scheduled task.

Much more information including time series, historic and aggregated data is available via the monitoring history GUI.  This gui pulls its data from the management REST API which in turn queries the Meters Database. 
You can use either the REST API or the query the Meters database directly to produce a report containing the desired information and email it.

Comment: But How do I automate the generation of excel generation?
If I can get that then rest can be done easily

Comment: scheduled tasks